# LazySequenceProtocol example not working

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand how to implement an extension that conforms to the LazySequenceProtocol.

So I followed the sample code from [Apple's API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/lazysequenceprotocol) as followings:

```
struct LazyScanIterator<Base : IteratorProtocol, ResultElement>
: IteratorProtocol {
    mutating func next() -> ResultElement? {
        return nextElement.map { result in
            nextElement = base.next().map { nextPartialResult(result, $0) }
            return result
        }
    }
    private var nextElement: ResultElement? // The next result of next().
    private var base: Base                  // The underlying iterator.
    private let nextPartialResult: (ResultElement, Base.Element) -> ResultElement
}

struct LazyScanSequence<Base: Sequence, ResultElement>
    : LazySequenceProtocol // Chained operations on self are lazy, too
{
    func makeIterator() -> LazyScanIterator<Base.Iterator, ResultElement> {
        return LazyScanIterator(nextElement: initial, base: base.makeIterator(), nextPartialResult)
    }

    private let base: Base
    private let initial: ResultElement
    private let nextPartialResult: (ResultElement, Base.Iterator.Element) -> ResultElement
}

extension LazySequenceProtocol {
    func scan<ResultElement>(
        _ initial: ResultElement,
        _ nextPartialResult: (ResultElement, Iterator.Element) -> ResultElement
        ) -> LazyScanSequence<Self, ResultElement> {
        return LazyScanSequence(
            initial: initial, base: self, nextPartialResult)
    }
}
```

but XCode says,

> Cannot convert value of type 'ResultElement' to expected argument type '_?'

on the line `return LazyScanIterator(nextElement: initial, base: base.makeIterator(), nextPartialResult)`.

I wanted to make the error go away but nothing worked, so I just removed all codes from `mutating func next()` part in the `LazyScanIterator` struct and just returned `base.next()` and changed the type of `nextElement` with `ResultElement` instead of `ResultElement?`.

Well, the error went away but now I have a new one at the same line.

> Cannot convert value of type '(ResultElement, Base.Iterator.Element) -> ResultElement' to expected argument type '(_, _) -> _'

What is wrong with this sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the constructors doesn't exist.

this works well in my playground (written in Swift 3)

```
import Foundation

struct LazyScanIterator<Base : IteratorProtocol, ResultElement>
: IteratorProtocol {
    private var nextElement: ResultElement? // The next result of next().
    private var base: Base                  // The underlying iterator.
    private let nextPartialResult: (ResultElement, Base.Element) -> ResultElement

    mutating func next() -> ResultElement? {
        return nextElement.map { result in
            nextElement = base.next().map { nextPartialResult(result, $0) }
            return result
        }
    }

    init(nextElement: ResultElement, base: Base, nextPartialResult: @escaping (ResultElement, Base.Element) -> ResultElement) {
        self.nextElement = nextElement
        self.base = base
        self.nextPartialResult = nextPartialResult
    }
}

struct LazyScanSequence<Base: Sequence, ResultElement>
    : LazySequenceProtocol // Chained operations on self are lazy, too
{
    private let base: Base
    private let initial: ResultElement
    private let nextPartialResult: (ResultElement, Base.Iterator.Element) -> ResultElement

    func makeIterator() -> LazyScanIterator<Base.Iterator, ResultElement> {
        return LazyScanIterator(nextElement: initial, base: base.makeIterator(), nextPartialResult: nextPartialResult)
    }

    init(initial: ResultElement, base: Base, nextPartialResult: @escaping (ResultElement, Base.Iterator.Element) -> ResultElement) {
        self.initial = initial
        self.base = base
        self.nextPartialResult = nextPartialResult
    }
}

extension LazySequenceProtocol {
    func scan<ResultElement>(
        _ initial: ResultElement,
        _ nextPartialResult: @escaping (ResultElement, Iterator.Element) -> ResultElement
        ) -> LazyScanSequence<Self, ResultElement> {
        return LazyScanSequence(
            initial: initial, base: self, nextPartialResult: nextPartialResult)
    }
}

Array((1..<6).lazy.scan(0, +)) // will result : [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```